# Passing forwarding reference as lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider following code:

```
template <typename C>
void boo (C&& c) {
    c ();
}

template <typename T>
void foo (T&& v) { // (X)
    boo ([&v] () { some_func (std::forward<T> (v)); }); // (Y)
}
```

As far as I am concerned `v` in `(X)` is a forwarding reference. Is `v` also a forwarding reference in `(Y)` if it was captured by reference? Or should I write it differently to take advantage of forwarding?

Comment: As `v` is named, is it no longer a rvalue.

Comment: @Jarod42 sure, but couldn't find better way to describe it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I am concerned `v` in `(X)` is a forwarding reference.

Correct.

---

> Is `v` also a forwarding reference in `(Y)` if it was captured by reference?

No, `v` inside the body of the lambda refers to the anonymous closure instance's member variable `v`. Read

```
some_func (std::forward<T> (v));
```

as

```
some_func (std::forward<T> (this_closure->v));
```

Regardless, your use of `std::forward` here is correct - it will propagate temporariness if the `v` passed to `foo` was an rvalue.

This is because `std::forward<X>(x)` does this:

- If `X` is a value type or an rvalue reference type, it casts `x` to `X&&`.
- If `X` is an lvalue reference type, it casts `x` to `X&`.

`v` inside the lambda body is always an lvalue, but `std::forward<T>` depends on the type of the original type passed to `foo`.

**If you are sure that the lambda will be invoked once in the same call stack as the `foo` invocation, it is safe to capture by reference and `forward` in the body.**

Otherwise, you might want to [**"capture by perfect-forwarding"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html).

Comment: Note that if the lambda is called more than once, the result could be unexpected.